# How do I fix the build for mod_mono when it cannot find strndup on FreeBSD?

Tags: mono, apache2, mod-mono

I am installing mod_mono with Apache 2 on FreeBSD and I get the following error when Apache tries to load the mod_mono.so module.

> Cannot load
>   /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_mono.so
>   into server:
>   /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_mono.so:
>   Undefined symbol "strndup"

The prefix I set for Apache is /usr/local/apache and I have PHP and other modules working already. I found that strndup is referenced in roken.h in /usr/include and I tried the following additions to configure command but it did not work.

> --libdir=/usr/lib --includedir=/usr/include

I also tried...

> --with-mono-prefix=/usr

I do not know what to try next. It does not appear that mod_mono has many build options. Since Mono and XSP are both built successfully I just need mod_mono to work.

I appreciate any tips to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add strndup via implementing it:

```
ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include <config.h>
#endif
#if !_LIBC
# include "strndup.h"
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if !_LIBC
# include "strnlen.h"
# ifndef __strnlen
#  define __strnlen strnlen
# endif
#endif

#undef __strndup
#if _LIBC
# undef strndup
#endif

#ifndef weak_alias
# define __strndup strndup
#endif

char *
__strndup (s, n)
     const char *s;
     size_t n;
{
  size_t len = __strnlen (s, n);
  char *new = malloc (len + 1);

  if (new == NULL)
    return NULL;

  new[len] = '\0';
  return memcpy (new, s, len);
}
#ifdef libc_hidden_def
libc_hidden_def (__strndup)
#endif
#ifdef weak_alias
weak_alias (__strndup, strndup)
#endif
```